# Magento 2 analog for core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before(after)

Tags: magento2

I need to get a block after `_prepareLayout` and before `render` on the product page in Magento 2 (for example, for change title in head block).
I tried the `controller_action_layout_render_before` event but it doesn't work on the product page.

Answer (score 0):

/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php

```
    // Set layout instance to all generated block (trigger _prepareLayout method)
...
    $this->eventManager->dispatch('core_layout_block_create_after', ['block' => $block]);
...
```